# unresolved external symbol _LoadLibraryExA when compiling Lua

Tags: c, visual-c++, lua, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile Lua 5.3.1 for MSVC14. But I get the error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol _LoadLibraryExA referenced in function _lsys_load

The function in question being:

```
static void *lsys_load (lua_State *L, const char *path, int seeglb) {
  HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryExA(path, NULL, LUA_LLE_FLAGS);
  (void)(seeglb);  /* not used: symbols are 'global' by default */
  if (lib == NULL) pusherror(L);
  return lib;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's causing this error as I've successfully compiled it with MinGW before. What could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I guess when you compiled the lua static library with vs2015, you created a windows common static library project（Add New Project-> Visual C++ -> Windows->Static Library）, just like I did.

Delete you current project and create a win32 project will solve the problem.
Add New Project-> Visual C++ -> Win32, and then select the "static library" in the Wizards dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are linking `Kernel32.lib` with your program. `LoadLibraryExA` is defined in `Kernel32.lib`.

Check your project or build settings and make sure that `Kernel32.lib` should be present.

Comment: It should not happen. Then make sure correct Kernel32.lib is being linked and that should contain the required function.